# React native TypeError:undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04

TypeError:undefined is not an object(evaluating '_configProvider.remoteModuleConfig')

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need more to go off of :) [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Providing Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This error appears for me when running run-android on a freshly initalized project.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error, too, when creating a new project and running `react-native run-android`

Solution for me was:

1. Open the project in Android Studio to take advantage of the automatic gradle script running, then
2. Run `npm install` on the project

After that `react-native run-android` worked fine for me.